# How to pass features extracted from ccn1 to another cnn2?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

i made a cnn and from the third conv layer i extracted the features so that the shape is (600,12,12,128)

600 = training images
12x12128 = for a single image

Now i want to pass these to another cnn2 as an input But i want the input shape to be (600,12,12,1).

How to change the shape?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Lambda layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) in order to slice the output tensor from cnn1:

```
model=models.Sequential()

model.add(cnn1)

model.add(Lambda(lambda x : x[:,:,i])) # with 0 <= i < 128

model.add(cnn2)
```